# Upload File to FTP site throws error on particular line of code

Tags: asp.net

I am using the below code to upload file in FTP Site

```
Protected Sub FTPUpload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'FTP Server URL.
    Dim ftp As String = "myftpsitehere"

    'FTP Folder name. Leave blank if you want to upload to root folder.
    Dim ftpFolder As String = "Attachments/"

    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = Nothing

    'Read the FileName and convert it to Byte array.
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName)
    Using fileStream As New StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd())
        fileStream.Close()
    End Using

    Try
        'Create FTP Request.
        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(ftp & ftpFolder & fileName), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        'Enter FTP Server credentials.
        'request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")
        'request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential()
        request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length
        request.UsePassive = True
        request.UseBinary = True
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length
        request.EnableSsl = False

        Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)
            requestStream.Close()
        End Using

        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

        lblMessage.Text &= fileName & " uploaded.<br />"
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As WebException
        Throw New Exception(TryCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The above code uploads the file in ftp site when I test it in VS-2010 development mode.

When I try to upload file from the live website I am getting the below error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

> `Line 50:             'response.Close()
>   Line 51:         Catch ex As WebException
>   Line 52:             Throw New Exception(TryCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
>   Line 53:         End Try
>   Line 54:     End Sub`
>
> [Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.]
>      _Default.FTPUpload(Object sender, EventArgs e) in h:\root\home\Website-001\www\site15\Default.aspx.vb:52
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639

Comment: You are creating and throwing a new exception and that is the exception you are describing here. However the real error is the WebException, what does that contain? Debug and see the Message-property from that exception.

Comment: I am not getting any error in the development mode which works fine.  Getting error in live website so I am unable to fix where it occurs.

Comment: Anyway, you need to get/see/log whatever the ex.Message-property somehow so that you will see the real error message.